# Searching From same table twice in sql always returns value which is higher in rank

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table is this one:

```
name       email        password
amit       ami@g.com    yadav
yadav      yadav@f.com  yadav
```

and my procedure is this one

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[prcAdvanceSearchUser] 
@username varchar(50) 
as 
begin 
    select * 
    from userdetails 
    where (vname like @username + '%' 
           or vemail like @username + '%' 
           or vpassword like @username +'%') 
end
```

whenever  i am searching for a member named yadav... it shows amit on the top because amit has password=yadav
....

now my point is ... my result should be shown first according to name then by email and then by password or city (whtever column name is )..

is there any possible way for this kind of searching ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sorting according to column `tag` , all those rows returned after successfully matching against `vname` come on top as tag value = 1 , then in sort order comes tag value=2 for all those rows successfully matched against `vemail` and so on

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[prcAdvanceSearchUser] @username varchar(50) 
as 
begin 

select *,1 as tag from userdetails 
where vname like @username + '%' 

Union

select *,2 as tag from userdetails 
where vemail like @username + '%'

Union

select *,3 as tag from userdetails 
where vpassword like @username +'%'

order by tag

end
```

Comment: sry bro this is not working .... this will always show amit on the top ... i think u didnt got my point ..
my point is if amit has the same field in his vpassword field and someone other has same name ... the second one must be shown on the top ...

Comment: thanks a lot bro ... :) 
u made my day ..
if u dont mind is there any other way to contact you in future ??

Comment: i am active here on stackoverflow..u can post your problems here, will definetly get immediate response, if not from me thaen others, if question is clear and formatted... any ways plz mark as correct answer..

Comment: @user3437568: just post another question. There will be sufficient people to help you out.

Comment: @PatrickHofman row_number() can be used for rankingand in final select capture rank=1

Comment: @PatrickHofman ... you are absolutely right .. so wht should i do to avoid duplicates

Comment: Use the answer of @valex. His one does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN vname like @username + '%'    THEN 1
            WHEN vemail like @username + '%'   THEN 2  
            WHEN vpassword like @username +'%' THEN 3
       END as OrdNum
       userdetails.*, 

from userdetails 
where (vname like @username + '%' 
       or vemail like @username + '%' 
       or vpassword like @username +'%') 
ORDER BY OrdNum
```